# Wordpress custom post type and taxonomy still display all posts in post type

Tags: wordpress

Hey everyone I'm currently extremely frustrated and can not figure this out have looked all over the internet. I have a custom post type called "portfolio" and I have a taxonomy called "categories" which contains two categories "photography" and "catalog design". I'm using this code

```
            query_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'catalog-design',
                'terms' => 'catalog-design'
            )
        ));
```

For some reason it's not listening to the taxonomy and is just displaying everything in portfolio. I also tried this and it still didn't work

```
            query_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                            'category' => 'catalog-design'
        ));
```

If anybody know how to fix this it would be awesome also here is the code that creates everything

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio');
```

function portfolio() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Portfolio', 'edit and add portfolio items'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add Portfolio Item', 'Portfolio Item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item'),
    'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item'),
    'view_item' => __('View Portfolio'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/portfolio.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title', 'category', 'editor','thumbnail'),
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'client')
  ); 

register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'category' looks for an ID. Try:

```
query_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'category_name' => 'catalog-design'
));
```

Or:

```
$cat = get_cat_ID('catalog-design');
query_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'category' => $cat
));
```